# Update all products (When out of stock) Prestashop

Tags: database, prestashop

I need to change the **available for order** when out stock of all products.

I know is for the SQL way, but I don't know the table name, because **ps_product_shop** not have an option for this. and in the table **ps_stock_avaiable** only appears the products with the change of the option **When out of stock**.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Well i'm not sure what version of PrestaShop you use, but for 1.6 what you need is in:

**"ps_product"** table **"available_for_order"** field, change 1 or 0 to enable and disable for each product, or for all.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes is Prestashop 1.6 and in this case is "ps_product_shop" because is multishop. I change the value but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this sql request which will change the ps_stock_available table and field out_of_stock from '0' to '1':

```
UPDATE `ps_stock_available` SET `out_of_stock`=1
```